# With XML::Twig, is there a way to extract only entries with specific child entry

Tags: xml, perl

I have been using XML::Twig with perl for a while now. However I have come across the following problem and wondered if there was a solution. I have a large XML file and would like to extract a twig having a specific child entry. So, for example I might have the following structure:

```
<Sys>
    <FP>
        <Ent p="s">
            <v>6</v>
        </Ent>
        <Ent p="t">
            <v>60</v>
        </Ent>
        <Ent p="s">
            <v>10</v>
        </Ent>
    </FP>
</Sys>
```

Now I can get all the "Ent" parts which have an attribute p="s" with a command like:

```
my @val = ($file->root->get_xpath('/Sys/FP/Ent[@p="s"]'));
```

However I want to go a step further and only get those entries that have a child value "v" equal to say 6.

Can this be done and if so how? I understand that I could loop through the values I found above and extract the required ones. But in my example I have over 10000+ entries in the XML file of which only about 100 have the required attribute.

Please let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: try `$file->root->get_xpath('/Sys/FP/Ent[@p="s" and v="6"]')`

Comment: Error in xpath expression at 'v="6"'.  I don't see how that would work anyhow: p is an attribute, v isn't.

I'm not sure why looping over the results is so bad, though.
Have you tried using an iterator like next_elt ? 
Is that too memory-intensive? Too slow? Why do you not want to use a loop, specifically?